# Firemonkey desktop app VS mobile! delphi

Tags: delphi, android

игра быки и коровы - всё нормально работает на desktop_app, переделал под андройд выходит ошибка. как быть? большая ли разница между desk и mobile? 3d и hd ?

Comment: видимо, нужно переделать нормально.

> большая ли разница между desk и mobile

Да, достаточно большая.

Comment: спасибо всем. я таки не разобрался в чем у меня ошибка...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> большая ли разница между desk и mobile

Примерно такая же, как между гоночным балидом и вездесущей машиной, или походным катером и авианосцем. По идее FM платформа стирает некоторое различие именно в своём коде, т.к. компоненты FM одинаково-хорошо работают на Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android. Вывод: вы пишите не кросс-платформенный код.

Comment: > FM одинаково-хорошо работают

одинаково среднее работают

Comment: Я пока не сталкивался с этой проблемой :) Может не те компоненты? :D

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле - одно из основных отличий - это так называемые null-based strings. Традиционно, в Delphi нумерация символов в строке начинается с 1. В desktop версиях они это пока ещё поддерживают, а вот в мобильных отказались.

Для того, чтобы всё нормально работало и там и там, надо переделать методы работы со строками на работу через хелперы. То есть S[1] -> S.Chars(0); Length(S) -> S.Length итд. Точные названия функций не помню, это всё есть в хелпе, но смысл такой.

Кроме того я замечал ещё ряд отличий в работе некоторых классов под windows и под android. Но это уже надо смотреть отдельно.